# Disk Space Usage Profiling in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am running C++ program on Linux [Red Hat], This program creates temporary files on the Hard Disk to compute its result. I need to know how much space does this program use from the Disk while it is running. I could not able to change the source code to keep the files so I can subtract the size of the Program folder before and after producing the results. is there any profiling tool or command line that I can use to help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `du -h /path/todir` before and after the program run from the terminal, I suppose.

> du - estimate file space usage
>
> -h, --human-readable
>                 print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

If you need further options just take a look at `man du`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this command will not profile the disk usage during the running time of my program, It will print the disk space usage before and after depends on the created files on the Hard Disk. If the program creates temporary files during its running time and removes them will this command report the disk space usage of these files?

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of stats maintained in /proc/[pid]/io .

**From /proc man page :**

This file contains I/O statistics for the process, for
              example:

```
              # cat /proc/3828/io
              rchar: 323934931
              wchar: 323929600
              syscr: 632687
              syscw: 632675
              read_bytes: 0
              write_bytes: 323932160
              cancelled_write_bytes: 0

write_bytes: bytes written
                     Attempt to count the number of bytes which this process
                     caused to be sent to the storage layer.
```

You may write script something like ,

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
echo $1
rm /tmp/writtenBytes.txt
psout=`ps aux | grep "$1" | grep -v $0 | grep -v grep `
while [[ "$psout" != "" ]]
do
    pid=`echo $psout | awk '{print $2}'`
    cat /proc/$pid/io  | grep write  | grep -v cancelled >> /tmp/writtenBytes.txt   
    psout=`ps aux | grep "$1" | grep -v $0 | grep -v grep`
    echo $psout
    sleep 1
done
```

Run this script as

```
bash -x getIO.sh "postgres: stats collector"
```

This script will create file /tmp/writtenBytes.txt, containing number of bytes written by processes named "postgres: stats collector"